# python3 socket send recev 'bytes' object has no attribute 'read'

Tags: python, sockets, subprocess, send

I have two files: **client.py** and **server.py** that when run are connected by socket.
When I send a command to the client from the server, for example a simple `ls`, I use a function (in the client) called `subprocess.Popen` to execute it in the shell. However, the error bytes `object has no attribute 'read'` appears to me.

Is there any other way to execute a command other than the subprocess module?

Am I running subprocess correctly with the following call:

```
command = subprocess.Popen (args, shell = True, stdout = subprocess.PIPE, stderr = subprocess.PIPE)
```

Below I attached the code of the two programs.

**The server code is as follows:**

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import socket

def main():
    try:
        servidor = socket.socket()
        servidor.bind(('localhost',7777))
        servidor.listen(1)

        while True:
            client, direccion = servidor.accept()
            print('[+] Conexion de: {}'.format(direccion))

            while True:
                comando = input("<server>: ")
                client.send(comando.encode())
                result = client.recv(4096)
                print(result.decode())
    except Exception as e:
        print (e)

if __name__ == '__main__' :
    try:
        main()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        exit()
```

**The client code is as follows:**

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import socket
import subprocess
import shlex


def main():
    try:
        client = socket.socket()
        client.connect(('localhost', 7777))

        while True:
            datos = client.recv(4096)
            args = shlex.split(datos)
            comando = subprocess.Popen(args, shell=True,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
            
            if comando.stderr.read() != "":
                client.send("[-] Error de comando")
            else:
                cliente.send(comando.stdout.read())
    except Exception as e: 
        print (e)

if __name__ == '__main__' :
    try:    
        main()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        exit()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   args = shlex.split(datos)
```

datos is of type `bytes`, but `shlex.split` expects a `str`.

```
   args = shlex.split(datos.encode())
```

Comment: **The first thing I would like to thank is the response offered**  

When I run the following line:  


`args = shlex.split (data.encode ())`  


The following error message appears:  


'bytes' object has no attribute 'encode'  

Piece of client code:  

`data = client.recv (4096)
 args = shlex.split (data.encode ())
 command = subprocess.Popen (args, shell = True, stdout = subprocess.PIPE, stderr = subprocess.PIPE)`  


Thank you very much @Uku